# Can't open Java Lucene application in more than one computer

Tags: java, lucene

I developed a little software implementing Lucene to find files. But I'm trying to use it in my network, and if someone is with the software open I can't open it in another computer it just hangs. How can I fix it? Is it normal?

I have a git in case you want to read the code. [GitHub](https://github.com/matheusws/IRMaven)

Comment: Do you get a specific error message? It would help if you posted the exact error/exception in your question

Comment: There's no error message, it just hangs and when I close the application in the computer it opens.